# Error while using DebugDiag for debugging dump file

Tags: .net, dump, debugdiag

This is the first time I'm debugging or doing anything with a .dmp file. I'm using Debugdiag. When I run my Analysis, I get this error-

```
Analysis results may be incomplete because an error occurred while initializing the CLR diagnostic runtime for w3wp.DMP.

Dump File:  w3wp.DMP

Type:  DebugDiag.DotNet.DacNotFoundException

Message:  CLR is loaded in the target, but the correct dac file cannot be found. DacFileName: mscordacwks_Amd64_Amd64_10.0.30319.01.dll. DacLocation:
```

It says to fix this, I must do this:

```
To fix this problem, you can copy mscordacwks.dll from the server where the dump was taken and rename it to mscordacwks_Amd64_Amd64_10.0.30319.01.dll and add the path of the folder to the Symbol server path by going to Tools-> Options and Settings
```

I did it, and now I get the following error:

Dump File:  w3wp.DMP

Type:  Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.ClrDiagnosticsException

Message:  Failed to load dac: D:\Dumps\mscordacwks_Amd64_Amd64_10.0.30319.01.dll

```
Stack Trace:

Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.DacLibrary..ctor(DataTargetImpl dataTarget, String dacDll)

Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.DataTargetImpl.CreateRuntime(String dacFilename)

DebugDiag.DotNet.NetDbgObj.CreateRuntimeAndGetHeap(String dumpPath, IDbgObj3 legacyDebugger, String symbolPath, Boolean throwOnBitnessMismatch, Boolean loadClrHeap)

HResult: UnknownError
```

I had tried going through a few links, one being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550255/reading-net-4-0-dump-files-in-windbg). Not getting anything. How do I fix this and view the entire analysis for the dump file?

Comment: Have you seen that topic: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297911/failure-loading-dac-createdacinstance-failed-when-loading-dump-file-with-clrm) ? It says mainly about ClrMd but DebugDiag is based on that so maybe it will help.

Answer (score 4):

You should only get this if you are analyzing on a different machine than the dump came from.  The reason is simply that a different version of the mscordacwks.dll is in use.

To fix it, copy the mscordacwks.dll from the source machine to the analysis machine into a temporary directory (*NOT* the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.net directory).

Rename the copied mscordacwks.dll to mscordacwks_Amd64_Amd64_10.0.30319.01.dll.

Add the temporary directory to the symbol search path in the debugdiag analysis app.

Rerun your analysis.